# How can I inject a URL of a mock server to terraform's acceptance tests?

Tags: go, terraform, acceptance-testing

There's a whole section about acceptance tests for terraform provider on the [official](https://www.terraform.io/docs/extend/testing/acceptance-tests/index.html) website that is assumes I'm going to run it with a test account on a real infrastructure.

That said, in my case I can't use my real infrastructure and the plan is to use a mock server instead that I want to make tf provider / client talk to and I do have a specific variable for it:

```
provider "foo" {
  endpoint = var.endpoint
}

variable "endpoint" {
  type = string
  description = "Endpoint to talk to"
  default = "https://realinfra.com" % want to use "localhost:9090" (mock server's address) in tests instead
}
```

Can I set / pass it somehow in acceptance tests? Here's the minimal working [example](https://www.terraform.io/docs/extend/testing/acceptance-tests/testcase.html) of my test:

```
package example

// example.Widget represents a concrete Go type that represents an API resource
func TestAccExampleWidget_basic(t *testing.T) {
    var widgetBefore, widgetAfter example.Widget
    rName := acctest.RandStringFromCharSet(10, acctest.CharSetAlphaNum)

    resource.Test(t, resource.TestCase{
        PreCheck:     func() { testAccPreCheck(t) },
        Providers:    testAccProviders,
        CheckDestroy: testAccCheckExampleResourceDestroy,
        Steps: []resource.TestStep{
            {
                Config: testAccExampleResource(rName),
                Check: resource.ComposeTestCheckFunc(
                    testAccCheckExampleResourceExists("example_widget.foo", &widgetBefore),
                ),
            },
            {
                Config: testAccExampleResource_removedPolicy(rName),
                Check: resource.ComposeTestCheckFunc(
                    testAccCheckExampleResourceExists("example_widget.foo", &widgetAfter),
                ),
            },
        },
    })
}
```

In different words (or like a more general question), how would you set the values for variables in tf provider given that you've got:

```
func Provider() *schema.Provider {
    return &schema.Provider{
        Schema: map[string]*schema.Schema{
        ...,
        "endpoint": {
                Type:     schema.TypeString,
                Optional: true,
                Default:  "https://realinfra.com",
            },
        "email": {
                Type:        schema.TypeString,
                Optional:    true,
                DefaultFunc: schema.EnvDefaultFunc("FOO_USERNAME", ""),
            },
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways to do this:

### 1. Environment variable

Allow setting provider endpoint through env variable:

```golang
"endpoint": {
    Type:     schema.TypeString,
    Optional: true,
    DefaultFunc: schema.EnvDefaultFunc("FOO_ENDPOINT", "https://realinfra.com")
},
```

And require this env variable to be set in [`testAccPreCheck`](https://www.terraform.io/docs/extend/testing/acceptance-tests/testcase.html#precheck):

```golang
func testAccPreCheck(t *testing.T) {
  if v := os.Getenv("FOO_ENDPOINT"); v == "" {
    t.Fatal("FOO_ENDPOINT env must be set for acceptance tests")
  }
}
```

Then you can export this env var in your Makefile

### 2. Provide config in test cases

You can set your provider configuration inside test cases configs:

```golang
// define mock address
const mockServer = "http://localhost:9090"

func TestAccExampleWidget_basic(t *testing.T) {
    ...

    resource.Test(t, resource.TestCase{
        ...
        Steps: []resource.TestStep{
            {
                // pass mock server to configs
                Config: testAccExampleResource(rName, mockServer),
                ...
            },
        },
    })
}

func testAccExampleResource(resourceName, server string) string {
    return fmt.Sprintf(`
# use mock serer address to configure your provider inside test case config
provider "myprovider" {
  endpoint = "%s"
}

myresource "myprovider_something" "foo" {
  name = "%s"
}`, server, resourceName)
}
```

Note that you will need to do this for every test config.

### 3. Construct mock API client and pass it to test provider

Allow passing api client to provider consturctor:
`provider.go`

```golang
func New(client *myApiClient) *schema.Provider {
    provider := &schema.Provider{...}

    provider.ConfigureContextFunc = func(_ context.Context, data *schema.ResourceData) (interface{}, diag.Diagnostics) {
        // return mock client if provided
        if client != nil {
            return client, nil
        }
       
        // existing client config here
        ...
        return client, nil
    }
}
```

Update provider entrypoint as well with empty client:
`main.go`

```golang
func main() {
    plugin.Serve(&plugin.ServeOpts{
        ProviderFunc: func() *schema.Provider {
            return provider.New(nil)
        },
    })
}
```

Depending on how your API client is initialized, create mock and pass it to provider inside tests:
`provider_test.go`

```golang
var testAccProviderFactories map[string]func() (*schema.Provider, error)
var testAccProvider *schema.Provider
var client *myApiClient

func init() {
    client = &myApiClient{Endpoint: "http://localhost:9000"}
    testAccProvider = New(client)
    testAccProviderFactories = map[string]func() (*schema.Provider, error){
        "myprovider": func() (*schema.Provider, error) {
            return testAccProvider, nil
        },
    }
}
```

This approach was inspired by [keycloak provider tests](https://github.com/mrparkers/terraform-provider-keycloak/blob/master/provider/provider_test.go)